# The correct mathematical term for nth integral

Tags: integration, notation

I'm looking for a correct English term for the following concept:
$$
If(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt \\
g(x) = I(If(x)) \\
h(x) = I^{n}f(x)
$$

What should be the precise name of $h(x)$? So far I came up with:

- n-th order repeated integral
- n-th order integral
- nth order integral
- nth integral

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could probably call it any of those terms, but the interesting thing is how far it simplifies.  Thanks to [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration), we have

$$I^nf(x)=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\ dt$$

which is very helpful for deducing things like

$$\int_1^x\ln(t)\ dt=\int_1^x\int_1^t\frac1y\ dy\ dt=\frac1{1!}\int_1^x\frac{x-t}t\ dt=x\ln(x)-x+1$$

which is rather simple.

Comment: Simply Beautiful Answer!

Comment: No problem and thanks!

Comment: Is the above formula still valid when n is other than positive integer? Thank you

Comment: @blindProgrammer The "nth integral" loses it's meaning when n is not a positive integer. One can define such a thing using the above if one so wishes though.

Comment: How to use Cauchy's repeated integral formula when x is infinity ?

Comment: @PrasenjitDWakode You treat it as a limit when $x\to\infty$ like you would any improper integral.

Answer (score 3):

$f^{(-n)}(t)$ means nth antiderivative (indefinite integral) and $f^{(n)}(t)$ means nth derivative of $f(t)$

Write the notations as power of f written in round bracket. Positive power stands for derivative while negative power stands for antiderivative.

When n=0 , it would mean the function itself. I have seen these notations in many places.